# Log In como su desde código usando el comando system

Tags: c, qt, raspbian

Estoy trabajando con Raspbian y Qt en C. Hace poco instale mutt directamente en la consola para poder enviar correos desde la línea de comandos, hasta ahí todo funciona perfectamente.

El problema viene al intentar incorporar esa función dentro de mi código en Qt, utilizo el comando `system()` de `stdlib.h` para poder pasarle la línea de comandos directamente, pero me da un error.

El problema está en que para enviar correos usando mutt tengo que logearme como "sudo su" en la consola y posteriormente enviar el correo. Mi pregunta es, ¿hay alguna forma de logearme como "sudo su" desde el código en Qt, para que así me permita mandar correos desde el programa? Lo he intentado haciendo:

```
System("sudo su") 
System(Línea de comando de mutt para el correo)
```

Pero haciendo lo anterior, el programa logea como sudo su pero se cuelga en ese paso.

Comment: ¿`sprintf("sudo %s", buffer, cmd); system(buffer)` no funcionará?

Comment: No, el código se queda pillado cuando se logea como root. A partir de ahí no hace nada